# Rendering One Instance of Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to create an application that allows users to add patient records that contain name, phone and diagnosis. It gives them the ability to add new patients, edit current patients or entirely delete them.

I am rendering the name, phone, diagnosis, the edit-diganosis button and the EditDiagnosis component. The EditDiagnosis component renders a form in which the input fields are loaded already with the values entered by the user so that they can edit it.

The problem is that if I have more than 2 patient records and I click on the `edit-diganosis` button on the second record, it loads two instances of the `EditDiagnosis` component, one under the second record and that is intended and one under the first record and that is not what I want. I only want when I click on the `edit-diagnosis` button of a certain record, it only opens the form to edit this record, not all records.

I know I am doing something wrong but I cannot figure out how to associate each button with its own record.

The components I need help with are: PatientDiagnosis and EditDiagnosis

```js
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import PatientDiagnosis from './PatientDiagnosis';
import AddPatient from './AddPatient';
import DiagnosisForm from './DiagnosisForm';
import EditDiagnosis from './EditDiagnosis';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        patientsList: [],
        inEditMode: false,
        allowDelete: false
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        try {
            const data = localStorage.getItem('patientsList');
            const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
            if (parsedData) {
                this.setState(() => ({ patientsList: parsedData }));
            }
        } catch (e) {

        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(undefined, prevState) {
        if (prevState.patientsList.length !== this.state.patientsList.length) {
            const data = JSON.stringify(this.state.patientsList);
            localStorage.setItem('patientsList', data);
        }
    }

    addDiagnose = (patient) => {
        if(patient.name && patient.phone && patient.diagnosis) {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({ patientsList: prevState.patientsList.concat(patient)}));
        }
        else {
            return 'Please fill out all the fields to continue.';
        }
    }

    editDiagnose = (patient, id) => {
        if (!patient.name || !patient.phone || !patient.diagnosis) {
            return "Please fill out all the fields to continue.";
        }

        this.setState(prevState => {
            prevState.patientsList[id] = patient;
            return {
                patientsList: prevState.patientsList,
                inEditMode: !this.state.inEditMode
            }
        }
        )
    }

    toggleEdit = (id) => {
        console.log(id);
        this.setState(() => ({inEditMode: !this.state.inEditMode}))
        }

    deleteDiagnose = (patientToDelete) => {
        console.log(patientToDelete);
        this.setState(
            (prevState) => {
                prevState.patientsList.map(patient => console.log(patient));
                return {patientsList: prevState.patientsList.filter(patient => patientToDelete !==patient)};
            }
                
            
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <Header />
                <PatientDiagnosis
                patientsList={this.state.patientsList}
                toggleEdit={this.toggleEdit}
                inEditMode={this.state.inEditMode}
                deleteDiagnose={this.deleteDiagnose}
                editDiagnose={this.editDiagnose} />
                <AddPatient addDiagnose={this.addDiagnose} />

            </div>
        )
    }
}

const PatientDiagnosis = ({patientsList, deleteDiagnose, editDiagnose, inEditMode, toggleEdit}) => (
    <div>
    {patientsList.map((patient, index) => {
        console.log(inEditMode);
        return (
            <div key={index}>
            <h1>{patient.name}</h1>
            <h1>{patient.phone}</h1>
            <h1>{patient.diagnosis}</h1>
            <button onClick={e => {e.preventDefault(); toggleEdit(patient)}}>Edit Diagnosis</button>
            {inEditMode && <EditDiagnosis id={index} patient={patient} editDiagnose={editDiagnose} deleteDiagnose={deleteDiagnose}/>}
            </div>
        )
    })}
    </div>
    )


export default PatientDiagnosis;

export default class EditDiagnosis extends React.Component {
    state = {
        id: this.props.id,
        name: this.props.patient.name,
        phone: this.props.patient.phone,
        diagnosis: this.props.patient.diagnosis,
        error: undefined
    }
    editDiagnose = (e, id) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        id = this.state.id;
        const name = this.state.name;
        const phone = this.state.phone;
        const diagnosis = this.state.diagnosis;
        const patient = {name, phone, diagnosis}
        const error = this.props.editDiagnose(patient, id);
        this.setState(()=>({error}));
        if (!error) {
            e.target.elements.name.value = '';
            e.target.elements.phone.value = '';
            e.target.elements.diagnosis.value = '';
        }
    }

    toggleEdit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState(() => ({allowEdit: !this.state.allowEdit}))
    }

    changeName = (e) => {
        const name = e.target.value;
        this.setState(() => ({name}))
    }

    changePhone = (e) => {
        const phone = e.target.value;
        this.setState(() => ({phone}))
    }

    changeDiagnosis = (e) => {
        const diagnosis = e.target.value;
        this.setState(() => ({diagnosis}))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            {this.state.error && <p className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{this.state.error}</p>}
            {
                <form
                className="add-option"
                id="patient-form"
                onSubmit={this.editDiagnose}>
                <DiagnosisForm 
                changeName={this.changeName}
                changePhone={this.changePhone}
                changeDiagnosis={this.changeDiagnosis} 
                name={this.state.name} 
                phone={this.state.phone} 
                diagnosis={this.state.diagnosis} 
                editDiagnose={this.editDiagnose}/>
                <button className="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save Changes</button>
                <button 
                className="btn btn-danger"
                onClick={
                    e => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        console.log(this.props.deleteDiagnose);
                        this.props.deleteDiagnose(this.props.patient);
                    }
                }>Delete Diagnosis</button>
                </form>}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default class AddPatient extends React.Component {
    state = {
        error: undefined,
        addNewPatient: false
    }

    addNewPatient = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState(() => ({addNewPatient: !this.state.addNewPatient}));
    }

    cancelForm = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState(() => ({error: undefined, addNewPatient: !this.state.addNewPatient}));
    }

    handleAddOption = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const name = e.target.elements.name.value.trim().toLowerCase();
        const phone = e.target.elements.phone.value.trim().toLowerCase();
        const diagnosis = e.target.elements.diagnosis.value.trim().toLowerCase();
        const patient = {name, phone, diagnosis};
        const error = this.props.addDiagnose(patient);
        // this.setState(()=>({error, patientId: this.state.patientId + 1}));

        if(patient.name && patient.phone && patient.diagnosis) {
            this.setState(()=>({addNewPatient: !this.state.addNewPatient}));
        }

        if (!error) {
            e.target.elements.name.value = '';
            e.target.elements.phone.value = '';
            e.target.elements.diagnosis.value = '';
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="add-patient">
            {this.state.error && <p className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{this.state.error}</p>}
            {!this.state.addNewPatient && <button onClick={this.addNewPatient} className="btn btn-primary">Add A New Patient</button>}
            {this.state.addNewPatient &&
                <form
                className="add-option"
                id="patient-form"
                onSubmit={this.handleAddOption}>
                <DiagnosisForm handleAddOption={this.handleAddOption}/>
                <button className="btn btn-primary patient-form__btn" type="submit">Save</button>
                <button onClick={this.cancelForm} className="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button>
                </form>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your PatientDiagnosis component loops over all patients, but receives a single isEditing prop, so that won't work. You probably want to separate Patients and PatientDiagnosis into two components, so you can control each diagnosis display individualy

Comment: Thank you @Tommos Can you tell me which component does what because I am a bit confused now.

Comment: Conceptually you have an `App` that renders a list of `Patient`s, each patient has a `Diagnosis`. So it makes sense to have both a `Patient` and `Diagnosis` component. `Patient` component can then keep its own isEditingDiagnosis state (or you can put this state in your `Diagnosis` component also).

Comment: So by this you mean that I should create a `PatientDiagnosis` component that lives inside and is rendered by the `Patients` component. Right? @Tommos

Comment: Yes, but instead of `Patients` (could be useful also, but for now its probably just a loop), I would use `Patient` singular.

Comment: @Tommos So how can I render the records of each patient (like name, phone and diagnosis) in the singular `Patient` component without looping? The data is saved in an array in the App component state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187944/discussion-between-ahmed-magdy-and-tommos).

Comment: Something like this.state.patientsList.map(patientData => (<Patient
                patientData={patientData}
                deleteDiagnose={this.deleteDiagnose}
                editDiagnose={this.editDiagnose} /> ))